# How to Produce a new line in XSLT supporting chrome and IE?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, internet-explorer, xslt

I have an `xsl` file that will be applied on a meta data to produce a `csv` file.
I want to produce a new line so that records will be displayed line by line in the `csv` file.
I have tried the following:

First Approach: I declared a variable name to point to a new line :`<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />`
It worked on  IE 11 and not chrome.

Second Approach: I used `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` to produce a new line.
It worked chrome and not on IE 11.
Here is the link where I placed the style sheet and the metta data :
http://jsfiddle.net/Abadi/ss68uLv6/1/
There is also the csv.xsl file here from which the style sheet will be generated:http://jsfiddle.net/Abadi/r4tcn2yo/

Comment: Do you have `<xsl:output method="text"/>`? Consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. For instance if you only declare `<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />` you don't get any output at all. So please post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. Or at least post a URL to your sample.

Comment: For me the stylesheet used with http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015081201.xml produces the same output with IE 11, Firefox 40 and Chrome 44 on Windows 8.1. It declares `<xsl:param name="nl" select="'&#10;'"/>` and outputs `<xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>`.

Comment: Sorry for being late ,here is the link of the xsl style sheet.http://jsfiddle.net/Abadi/ss68uLv6/

Comment: It is working on IE11 and not on chrome.I even tried <xsl:output method="text"/>,but it didnt give sense.

Answer (score 0):

The stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015081201.xsl used with http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015081201.xml produces a text output document with three lines of text

```
foo,bar
John,Doe
Jane,Foe
```

with current versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome on Windows 8.1.

The XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:param name="nl" select="'&#10;'"/>
<xsl:param name="sep" select="','"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/record[1]/*" mode="cols"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/record"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record/*" mode="cols">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record/*">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Here is the link of the xsl style sheet I am using : http://jsfiddle.net/Abadi/ss68uLv6/

Comment: That stylesheet outputs HTML and not plain text. CSV is plain text and not HTML.

Comment: The csv file will be generated using javascript.

Comment: Consider to edit your question and insert samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I placed the style sheet and the metta data in this link :http://jsfiddle.net/Abadi/ss68uLv6/1/

Comment: I don't see any Javascript there.

Comment: There is also the csv.xsl file here from which the style sheet will be generated:http://jsfiddle.net/Abadi/r4tcn2yo/

Comment: In the javascript side,var xr=sCsv.split("\n") is  NULL on chrome and not NULL on IE 11.

Comment: sCsv = processor.transformToDocument(xData);
 
 if(sCsv != null && sCsv != ""){
    var i=sCsv.indexOf("<pre>");
    var j=sCsv.indexOf("</pre>",i);
    if(j>0) sCsv=sCsv.substr(i+5,j-i-5)  
    var xr=sCsv.split("\n")
    for(i=1;i<xr.length;i++){
      var xc=xr[i].split("]_[")
      for(j=0;j<xc.length-1;j++){
        xc[j]=jstable.f_formatCellX(xc[j]);
      }
      xr[i]=xc.join(",");
    };
    sCsv=xr.join("\n");  
  }

Comment: Please edit your question and provide minimal but complete snippets allowing us to reproduce the problem.